# Put a Star notation in html

Tags: html, web

I want to put a star notation in my html page."#x2605;" i know that this one is for solid star notation.but black in color.i need the star in RED color.how can i achive this.
help me..

Comment: Like <font color=red>★</font> (or cleaner with a span and a style) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YYS7z/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

html:

```
<span class="red-star">★</span>
```

css:

```
.red-star {
    color: red;
}
```

Font tags are depreciated in html5. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2

Answer (score 5):

HTML :

```
<span>Date of Birth <sup class="star">*</sup> </span>
```

CSS :

```
.star{
color:red;
}
```

The sup tag defines superscript text which appears half a character above the normal line. So the star mark will appear little above the normal text label.

Answer (score 3):

That star is just a character like any other. The only difference is that you use a unicode notation for this character. In a similar fashion, you could write `&65;` for a capital `A`.

Anyway, you can style it just like any other text, for instance using CSS:

In HTML:

```
<span class="star">&#x2605;</span>
```

In CSS:

```
.star {
   color: red; /* Make it red */
   font-size: 200%; /* Make it twice as large */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
.star{
color:red;
}
```

In HTML:

```
<span class="star">*</span
```

Note: For ★: In browser instead of ★, it is displaying â. And if we give Unicode then we are getting the star beside the word or phrase but actually we usually keep it bit upside of the word or phrase in order to mention the field as mandatory.